# Javascript - change r attribute of circle wrapped in #shadow-root

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

My html tree looks as follows:

```
<svg id="floating-button-svg" style={{fill: `${floatingButton.backgroundColor}`}}>
  <use id="use-tag" href="
     <svg>
       <circle id="semi-circle" class="cls-1" cx="500" cy="500" r="50"/>
     </svg>"
  />
</svg>
```

Afer compilation the href dissolves to `data:image/svg+xml;base64,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#semi-circle`
If anyone wants to test it, please replace the value in the href above with this link.

I am trying to change the radius of the circle through

```
document.getElementById('use-tag').setAttribute('r', '25')
```

but instead it only gives `use` an attribute of `r=25`. Is there any way I can change the radius of the circle? I have tried to fetch it using

```
 getElementById
```

but it just gives me null (I'm assuming because it's wrapped in a shadow root).

edit: The gist of the problem here I believe is that I am trying to change the attributes of a closed shadow root which is impossible to achieve. So can someone please tell me why am I get a *closed* root instead of an *open* one? And how can I get an *open* one?

edit: Here is a demo of this situation: https://codesandbox.io/embed/smoosh-sun-nnevd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you please add the html markup you tried :)

Comment: I tried ```document.getElementById('use-tag').setAttribute('r', '25') ```. Please let me know any other information you might need.

Comment: This is how you tried the js, we need the html mark up, eg.`<div> <svg><circle /></svg></div>`

Comment: I have updated the markup.

Comment: since you have direct access to the circle element ( id semi-circle ), why are you using shadow Dom ??

Comment: document.getElementById('semi-circle') returns me `null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208488/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-eren555).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have direct access to circle with id `semi-circle`, you can update it as the below snippet.

The snippet is running under a setTimeout to show the difference.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var circle = document.getElementById('semi-circle');
  circle.setAttribute('r', 60)
}, 3000)
```

```html
<svg id="floating-button-svg" height="100" width="100">
  <circle id="semi-circle" class="cls-1"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

You can also do it in another way, check the snippet

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var circle = document.getElementById('floating-button-svg');
  circle.firstElementChild.setAttribute('r', 60)
}, 1500)
```

```html
<svg id="floating-button-svg" height="400" width="400">
      <circle id="semi-circle" class="cls-1"  cx="80" cy="80" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: As I have mentioned above, the svg with the `floating-button-svg` is wrapped in a `use` tag which is placing the svg in a closed shadow root element which prevents me from fetching the circle element directly.

Comment: @Eren555 can you share the exact markup, your markup in the question is broken

Comment: @Eren555, please add the correct mark up, or please add a working snippet here, will help to solve :)

Comment: I believe the href in my initial markup for causing the issue for you. I just added that to show what the structure of my svg was. I have updated my answer and given the href that'll display the svg. Please check it out.